# Searching PyPI by topic

Tags: python, pip, package-managers, pypi

For every python package you can specify a [list of classifiers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=list_classifiers). Among others there is a `Topic` classifier, that puts the package in the specified categories that can be [browsed on `PyPI`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=browse).

For example, [`numpy`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/setup.py#L42-43) has the following topics:

```
Topic :: Software Development
Topic :: Scientific/Engineering
```

Is there a way to search by topic programmatically using `pip search` or other third-party libraries?

Comment: `pip search` should include a "by topic" search!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can search PyPI by classifier via the [XMLRPC API](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIXmlRpc), using the [`browse()`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIXmlRpc#line-143) method:

```py
try:
    import xmlrpclib  # Python 2
except ImportError:
    import xmlrpc.client as xmlrpclib  # Python 3

pypi = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://pypi.python.org/pypi')

packages = pypi.browse([
    "Topic :: Software Development",
    "Topic :: Scientific/Engineering",
])
```

In the example above, `packages` contains a list of `[package, version]` lists for all packages which satisfy both the "Topic :: Software Development" and "Topic :: Scientific/Engineering" classifiers:

```
>>> {pkg: ver for pkg, ver in packages if "numpy" in pkg}
{
    'nose-numpyseterr': '0.1',
    'msgpack-numpy': '0.3.2',
    'numpy': '1.8.1',
    'idx2numpy': '1.0b'
}
```

From there, you can retrieve more information about a given release:

```
>>> release = pypi.release_data('numpy', '1.8.1')
>>> release['download_url']
'http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/'
>>> release['platform']
'Windows,Linux,Solaris,Mac OS-X,Unix'
>>> release['downloads']
{
    'last_day': 5818,
    'last_month': 187688,
    'last_week': 44764
}
```

... etc.

Comment: [XmlRpc is deprecated](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIXmlRpc)