# Getting [Errno socket error] [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version

Tags: python-2.7, ssl

I'm getting this error and it can't be resolved from the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316292/ssl-sslerror-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version) answers. I have to use Python2.7. Please suggest solutions for this version.

```
Downloading and unzipping file ui-sortable-src0.17.1 to     ./third_party/static
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/install_third_party.py", line 343, in <module>
    _install_third_party_libs()
  File "scripts/install_third_party.py", line 330, in _install_third_party_libs
    download_manifest_files(MANIFEST_FILE_PATH)
  File "scripts/install_third_party.py", line 308, in download_manifest_files
    dependency_zip_root_name, dependency_target_root_name)
  File "scripts/install_third_party.py", line 124, in download_and_unzip_files
    urllib.urlretrieve(source_url, TMP_UNZIP_PATH)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
    return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 245, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 443, in open_https
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1038, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 882, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 844, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1263, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 363, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 611, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 840, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
IOError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661)
```