# Unable to update/add any package using PIP in python2.6

Tags: ssl, pip, python-2.6

Python Version - Python 2.6.9

PIP Version - pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)

**I Tried using all the available options on stackoverflow, but nothing worked out for me !**

**I don't want to upgrade my Python and want to install packages**

Whenever I run `pip install <some package>` it gives this error -

> Collecting ndg-httpsclient
>   /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pip/*vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl*.py:318:
>   SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI
>   (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this
>   platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS
>   certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a
>   newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
>   SNIMissingWarning
>   /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pip/*vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl*.py:122:
>   InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
>   This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause
>   certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of
>   Python to solve this. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
>   InsecurePlatformWarning   Could not fetch URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/ndg-httpsclient/: There was a problem
>   confirming the ssl certificate: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:497:
>   error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert
>   protocol version - skipping   Could not find a version that satisfies
>   the requirement ndg-httpsclient (from versions: ) No matching
>   distribution found for ndg-httpsclient
>   /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pip/*vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl*.py:122:
>   InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
>   This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause
>   certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of
>   Python to solve this. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
>   InsecurePlatformWarning

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssl.SSLError: tlsv1 alert protocol version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316292/ssl-sslerror-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: You have to upgrade everything related to SSL — OpenSSL, Python, pip. There is no way around it.