# Error in upgrading tensorflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I ran into a problem while upgrading the `tensorflow`. I currently use 0.12.1 version. Here is the message I got.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/peymanghahremani/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/peymanghahremani/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/Users/peymanghahremani/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/Users/peymanghahremani/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/Users/peymanghahremani/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/Users/peymanghahremani/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
hashes=hashes
  File "/Users/peymanghahremani/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
hashes)
  File "/Users/peymanghahremani/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 853, in _download_http_url
stream=True,
  File "/Users/peymanghahremani/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/peymanghahremani/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/peymanghahremani/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/peymanghahremani/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/peymanghahremani/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/Users/peymanghahremani/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590)
```

Comment: Did you try the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316292/ssl-sslerror-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version ?

Comment: Are you still facing the `SSLError` when trying to upgrade TensorFlow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue with TensorFlow but rather an issue with your version of OpenSSL. You can check your current version on OSX with:

```
$ python3 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
```

Then upgrade your version with:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install openssl
```