# sudo easy_install pip not working

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I'm having trouble executing the `sudo easy_install pip` command on my mac.  I'm not behind a firewall.  I'm using python version 2.7.10. The version of macOS Sierra is 10.12.4.  Here is the error I receive:

```
Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')
```

Comment: Have you tried updating openSSL? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316292/ssl-sslerror-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssl.SSLError: tlsv1 alert protocol version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316292/ssl-sslerror-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: @phd Could you point me to the part that is a duplication?  It appears that the linked question is referring to someone trying to create a python script.  I'm trying to install pip.

Comment: *update OpenSSL…updated Python to the latest version* You need to update everything related to SSL — OpenSSL, Python and pip.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution using `brew` to install `pyenv`.  Solution was found [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli#install-with-pyenv) but I only needed the parts up to when it uses `pip`.

```
# Install PyEnv (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation)
$ brew update
$ brew install pyenv

# Initialize pyenv using bash_profile
$ echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi\nexport PATH="~/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
# or using zshrc
$ echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi\nexport PATH="~/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

# restart the shell
$ exec "$SHELL"

# Install Python 2.7
$ pyenv install 2.7.14
$ pyenv local 2.7.14
```

After completing those steps I ran `sudo easy_install pip` again and eureka!  It worked.