# SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am very new to Python world, so please be patient with me.
I have a Mac running High Sierra (10.13.4). I installed Python on it and I now have two Python 2.7.10 and 3.6.5
As per my understanding 2.7.10 is default for Mac and I should not tinker with it.
Now, I am trying to connect Python3 to MySQL. I am running following command:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

but facing an error

```
Collecting MySQL-python3
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/mysql-python3/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQL-python3 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for MySQL-python3
```

I tried the solution provided here

[ssl.SSLError: tlsv1 alert protocol version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316292/ssl-sslerror-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

openssl 1.0.2o_1
pip --version: pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)

I tried to install virtualenv by running following commend:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

but still getting an error:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for virtualenv
```

Can someone please help me out here? I am trying to find answers my own but have failed so far, so need help.

Comment: I updated PIP by command:  curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3  Then ran "pip3 install MySQL-python" and got this error  "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/d6/z8wr3dh57fbby5slmzdznd180000gn/T/pip-install-kce4n_wc/MySQL-python/"

Comment: Any help..anyone