# pip install gitpython, Pip search returns a stack trace. i think pip needs update, but getting ssl error

Tags: python, pip

Seems like search is causing an SSL error, when attempting to do an install it couldnt find the right package. When i did a search it is giving an ssl issue

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590)
```

and lastly if i try to upgrade pip in an attempt to resolve the issue, it also has a SSL issue:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
```

*EDIT* This looks like an outdated SSL issue related to openessl due to my mac.  That being said, it might be a duplicate of [ssl.SSLError: tlsv1 alert protocol version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316292/ssl-sslerror-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version) but i am attempting to follow it in order to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a 2 pronged answer.

1:  Update openssl.

```
brew update
brew install openssl
```

2: to get gitPython, pip will still fail.  The issue is that for some reason despite gitpython working for 2.7, it doesnt like it.  I confirmed that `pyton3.6 -m pip install gitpython` works, but when doing it in pip using 2.7,

```
pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
pip install gitpython
    Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/smmap'
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

When attempting to upgrade pip i didnt have authority, and similarly when I sudo pip, it didnt like it either.

Ultimately, Since i am a 3.6 person, this solved my issues but I wanted to give insight for people using 2.7 for some reason.