# How to get rid off ssl error when i'm trying to deploy my app at digitalocean?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, web-deployment, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy my application to Digitalocean with docker and docker-compose. But I'm still facing this error

```
ERROR: SSL error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='host', port=2376): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1.25/containers/json?all=1&limit=-1&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dappname%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D&trunc_cmd=0&size=0 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:726)'),))
```

What i've did:

1. docker-machine create --driver=digitalocean --digitalocean-access-token=mytoken --digitalocean-size=1gb app
2. eval $(docker-machine env app)
3. And after these steps I'm trying docker-compose up -d and getting the error from above

Whats the problem, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a problem with your SSL configs on your computer. 
This SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316292/ssl-sslerror-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version) has several answers that might help you with fixing your problem.