# How causes error:1400442E:SSL and how to resolve it

Tags: ssl, cloudflare, lets-encrypt

My client app here at https://nametalkam.com hosted on digitalocean(cenTOS, nginx) is throwing error

> Error: The requested resource could not be loaded. libcurl returned
>   the error: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1
>   alert protocol version

When access from outside my location or some locations. I said this because it works fine on my location that i didn't even know the error exists. When some clients from europe visits the link, they reported the issue. Also

```
running curl https://nametalkam.com
```

returns

> curl: (35) error:1400442E:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:tlsv1
>   alert protocol version

So evidently, something is wrong. Please what causes this, how do i address it and why does it work for me ? Any help will be appreciated.

**More Information**

The site uses ssl certicate configured using letseencrypt, and another coming from cloudflare.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ssl.SSLError: tlsv1 alert protocol version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316292/ssl-sslerror-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)