# TSLV1 Alert error when trying to import CSV file on Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I'm trying to run some code on Python 2.7 to work on a CSV data set.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.stats.govt.nz/assets/Uploads/Injury-statistics/Injury-statistics-work-related-claims-2018/Download-data/injury-statistics-work-related-claims-2018-csv.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

For some reason, I keep getting this error :

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590)>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm able to run it, by giving `encoding='unicode-escape'`, can you download that csv and try with the file name and see if that works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ssl.SSLError: tlsv1 alert protocol version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316292/ssl-sslerror-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: @NYC Coder Still getting the same error with the statement encoding='unicode-escape'