# yum errors on CentOS 5

Tags: python, linux, yum, centos5

I have a Virtualbox VM with CentOS 5 and I'm discovering problems using yum.
I know that CentOS 5 is not supported by several years but I'm not prone to update the OS now.

In particular I am having troubles in command like:

yum update yum
yum update
yum install

And the error that comes out always report some paths to python files and this string that I don't understand:

> M2Crypto.SSL.SSLError: tlsv1 alert protocol version

Hope y'all got some tips or solution for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ssl.SSLError: tlsv1 alert protocol version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316292/ssl-sslerror-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Comment: Yes, looks like you changed the default openssl to a later alien version.