# How to handle aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientOSError: [Errno 1] [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:2624)

Tags: python, tls1.2, aiohttp

I occasionally run into a TLSV1 error (might be because I am on a VPN) when making HTTP calls via `aiohttp`. I have read a bit about the error in this SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316292/ssl-sslerror-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version).

but as noted in the comments, it is not easy to handle this error via raw `try-except` logic. Is there a work-around way to `except` this error and handle it when it occurs?

I tried using a few things:

```
try:
    # Make a request and check for status
    response.raise_for_status()
except aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientOSError:
    # Do something

except Exception:
    # Do something else
```

But the error passes through both without being able to be handled..

Comment: It's interesting, do you use any `ssl.SSLContext` for your aiohttp session / request? Also, which python version do you use?

Comment: I'm not sure if that will help and if easy to test for you, but you can try the following: ssl_ctx = ssl.create_default_context();
ssl_ctx.set_ciphers("DEFAULT");
session.request (or session.get/post whatever)  ssl=ssl_ctx

Comment: @VitaliiVolkov Thanks for this recommendation. I'll give it a try.